# Scrollable listview springs back to top when scrolling down in flutter

Tags: layout, flutter

I have implemented an offset to force down the listview one quarter of the height of the screen, to accommodate for an image shown above the listview (not in code). But now when I scroll down to the last tile, the listview jumps back up again.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  var data = [
    {
      "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    },
    {
      "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    },
    {
      "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    },
    {
      "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    },
    {
      "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Transform.translate(
            offset:
                new Offset(0.0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
            child: new ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              primary: true,
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {
                return ListItem(
                    title: data[index]["title"],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  String title;

  ListItem({this.title});

  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => new _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(width: 10.0, height: 190.0, color: Colors.black),
        new Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
                      child: new Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(
                    widget.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The code is expected to generate a scrollable list, where you can stop at any place in the list without it scrolling back to the top automatically.

Comment: I tried your code and it is not scrolling back to the top automatically. The problem is not coming from the code that you posted above.

Comment: @ProgrammingDude Strange... Are you sure you have scrolled all the way down to the last element? Exactly this code replicates this bug for me on multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Yes, the problem might come from somewhere else. If you create a new project with only the code you posted above, do you have the same problem?

Comment: Problem still persists. (new project) Here you can see how the listview scrolls away from the last element automatically: https://giphy.com/gifs/RfZ5475DkEu8LFVrLz

Comment: I use an Android emulator, so that might be the difference in the behavior between you and me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you've mentioned can't be replicated in the code snippet provided. It's likely that a different part of your project causes the issue and isn't included in the sample.

I've tried it on both Android...

[image: Android]

...and iOS.

[image: iOS]

Even the parallax scroll effect shouldn't cause a bounce that'll get the scroll position back to the top.

Have you tried updating the Flutter version that you're using and see if the same behavior occurs? You can update the Flutter version by running `flutter upgrade` on the Terminal.